# Зациклилась привязка - почему так происходит?

Tags: c#, maui

Зациклилось свойство

Как делать правильно ?

Свойство M:

```
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<string> input;
```

Свойство VM:

```
    public string Input
    {
        get => ListToString(_myModel.Input);
        
        set
        {
            _myModel.Input = StringToList(value);
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Метод обрабатывающий события от M в VM:

```
    private void MyModelPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Input":
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Input));
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Неизвестный аргумент");
        }
    }
```

Методы VM:

```
    private string ListToString(List<string> list)
    {
        if (list != null)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new();

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
                {
                    stringBuilder.AppendLine(item);
                }
            }
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }


    private List<string> StringToList(string text) 
    {
        return text.Split('\r').ToList();
    }
```

В V -> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Editor

```
        <Editor Text="{Binding Input}"
                Margin="10,0" 
                WidthRequest="300"
                HeightRequest="300" 
                AutoSize="TextChanges"/>
```

Comment: Я вам советую отказаться от MVVMToolkit и реализовывать все это руками, так вы больше поймете, и меньше будете ловить странности, которые не можете объяснить. Используйте сторонние библиотеки только тогда, когда вы знаете хорошо основу. Просто сейчас вы мешаете все, делая кучу лишнего, и странного. Вот допустим, зачем вам `MyModelPropertyChanged`? Чтоб оповещать об изменении свойства, когда изменилось другое? Ок... Для этого существует `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(...)]`, только вот ваша модель не должна знать ничего про VM, а значит и INPC в модели делать, наверно не лучшая идея.

Comment: Или например `set { _myModel.Input = StringToList(value);`, вы переопределяете сеттер свойства, чтоб добавить туда логику, ок... Только MvvmToolkit делает вам метод, который вы можете переопределить, для каждого свойства, вам достаточно создать его, что-то по типу `partial void OnInputChanged(string value){ ... }` (ключевым тут является соответствие с именем свойства), и вот уже мы в `set` ничего не пишем. Ну и вообще, странная конвертация как по мне, ибо конвертации место в конверторах, а не в VM...

Comment: Что касается зацикливания - поставьте точку остановки, и через F10 пройдитесь по своему коду, и посмотрите что и после чего вызывается, поймете что не так.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ но VM же должна знать об измененях свойства модели (модель с бизнес-логикой) ? Как ещё можно VM уведомлять ?

Comment: Не, я не говорю, что использовать INPC в модели не правильно, этот интерфейс созданный специально для оповещения об изменениях свойства. Я клоню к тому, что у вашей модели скорей всего не надо следить за всеми свойствами, вам достаточно простого события, и все. Ну, скажем база учеников, вам надо где-то знать, что добавился новый ученик, вы делаете в модели событие "OnNewStudent", и тригерите его в модели при добавлении, ну а где надо подписываетесь и получаете сразу нужного нового ученика, готово. С INPC вы много лишнего делаете, что мне кажется вам даже не нужно.

Comment: Ну а имея простое такое событие, вам и вовсе в модели не понадобиться зависимость в виде MvvmToolkit, она станет независимая, универсальная, чем и должна быть модель.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в принципе, я понимаю `INotifyPropertyChanged` и эту часть библиотеки MVVMToolkit, просто тупанул... меняя свойство VM - которое меняет свойство M, затем VM получает уведомление по этому же свойству и делает всё тоже самое по кругу). Но не могу сообразить как делать иначе. Так как Model получив изменения в Input должна его изменить и VM должна забрать изменнёный Input.

Comment: Что-то типа [этого](https://pastebin.com/J0vvdTJ7) у вас должно быть, если использовать MVVMToolkit. Все, что в регионе `DEBUG` это чисто для вывода отладочной информации в окно вывода студии, там увидите, что свойства успешно будут меняться. Обратите внимание, я не переопределяю свойства, я вообще их не трогаю, у меня их даже нет, есть только приватные поля и `partial` методы, по которым я что-то делаю (вывожу в отладку, меняю значение свойству). Также обратите внимание, что я по событию `Model_PropertyChanged` не "тригерю" обновления свойства, а лишь устанавливаю ему новое значение.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ оО - огонь - спасибо за пример! А у меня проблема была `Split('\r')` `stringBuilder.AppendLine(item);` и `'\n'` бесконечно тригерила( + я не делал сравнения при добавлении различаются / не различаются

Comment: Повторю, не задача VM конвертировать данные в "читаемый вид". Вот у вас есть коллекция, вы к примеру хотите его вывести в текстовое поле через запятую. Вопрос - Текстовое поле и его отображение, это какой слой? Правильно, UI, то есть View. Почему тогда коллекцию в "UI вид" переводит ViewModel слой? Почему за UI отвечает ViewModel? Это задача UI и ее конверторов, а в VM и M данные должны остаться неизменными.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да - да - это я понял, стараюсь разносить всё по своим местам. Теперь конверторы будут у конвертеров)